# Can the queue be determined from an executing block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue

On iOS/Objective-C, given an executing NSBlockOperation, is it possible to determine which queue the operation is associated with? Determining if one is on the main thread is pretty obvious, but what about operations in the background?

Comment: I am fine with the edits, but this would also beg the question of how one could map from a dispatch queue to an NSOperationQueue? My original wording was (deliberately) more generic.

Comment: Yeah, "current `NSOperationQueue`" and "current dispatch queue" are two different questions. I'd suggest rolling back or editing further.

Comment: @xyzzycoder Rolled it back a bit.

Comment: What you're ultimately trying to achieve might be important here. An `NSOperationQueue` does use a private dispatch queue to get things done, but you shouldn't try to use that dispatch queue yourself. Are you just curious, or are you trying to do something in particular?

Comment: Josh, I am programming to the NSOperationQueue layer in this case, so the scenario where one is going direct to GCD is just for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
[NSOperationQueue currentQueue];
```

From the docs:

> You can use this method from within a running operation object to get
>   a reference to the operation queue that started it. Calling this
>   method from outside the context of a running operation typically
>   results in nil being returned.

Comment: this answers the modified answer only. he originally asked about the dispatch queue in use... don't think operationQueue==dispatchQueue

Comment: It would be useful to understand both scenarios.

Comment: IMO getting the operationQueue you run on is useless as it will always be the one you added the operation to. internally though it may well be ANY other thread/gcd queue

Comment: I was answering the question I saw WRT an `NSBlockOperation`. The comments on dispatch queues are correct. Different animal.

Comment: I am programming to the NSOperationQueue in this particular case, but I was also curious about the scenario where one is working directly with GCD (just for curiosity's sake).

Answer (score 0):

There is a DEPRECATED method: `dispatch_get_current_queue()`

BUT apple really doesn't like it because it isn't safe or may lead to deadlocks or .. I didn't fully get the issue ;)